# Why do tensorflow RNN history + sample prediction graphs look so different from the training dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensor

I've been working with this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#predict_a_single_step_future

and I've gotten to the point where I'm making sample predictions but if you look at the prediction graphs linked above, I'm already a tad confused because the history looks different in each one of those graphs - but it's my natural inclination that history should always be the constant??

I'm currently at this step: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_model

In my specific case, here is my data set with 5033 observations of a single feature:

[image]

and here is my sample prediction:

[image]

I'm following everything in the tutorial I linked verbatim, with the exception of some properties because I wanted to try using a different dataset.

```
training_coef: 0.8 # standard 80/20 split between training + validation
step_size: 1 # tutorial had 30
batch_size: 256 # same as tutorial
buffer_size: 10000 # same as tutorial
future_target: 100 # tutorial had 72
past_history: 4000 # tutorial had 720
```

### tldr: can someone explain why the history line in the linked tutorial is different from the sample data itself, and then changes depending on the past_history?

#### IF you want to try running what I have locally for yourself and debugging it, I'm on CUDA 10.1 and tensorflow==2.1.0, and I'll upload the code and sample data sets for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plots looks different because you're plotting only the first 4000 points on the second figure. If you look more closely, you'll realize that "0" on your fist figure points at (about) 2016-01-14. The second plot is a sliced and rescaled copy of the first one.

Comment: I tried to see it before and I guess it sort of makes sense the way you put it. Does it look like it's overfitting?